# Center two col-sm-6 in a row + some basic boostrap confusion

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to teach myself how to effectively center things using bootstrap. Centering is something I really struggle with, even after reading a ton of other SO posts asking the same question.

Why do we have to wrap the cols in a row, and then wrap that row in a container? What does this actually do?

```css
body {
  background-color:pink;
}
    
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.col-sm-6 {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 1%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class = "container">
  <div class = "row">
  <div class = "col-sm-6"></div>
  <div class = "col-sm-6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cLw2ajro/)

Comment: You haven't included bootstrap in your fiddle.  `col-md-6` would make your columns 6-wide out of 12, or 50%.  There would be no need to center them horizontally.

Comment: bootstrap 3 or 4 ?

Comment: sorry, bootstrap 4 - updated fiddle

Comment: Can you post the link to your updated fiddle?  Also, why are you overriding `.col-sm-6` class in CSS?  This is the base bootstrap class and should not be overwritten width a fixed `px` width.  It defeats the purpose of bootstrap.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cLw2ajro/5/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cLw2ajro/6/ updated fiddle

Comment: but what if you also wanted them to stay in the same row when you minimize the window?

Comment: Jonathan is correct.  You should not be over writing the col- css, it defeats the purpose of using the bootstrap grid system.  Don't even bother using the bootstrap classes if that is what you are going to do, it will only make your life harder.  You should carefully read the grid system documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/. I'm not sure what look you are trying to achieve, but I'm quite certain there are bootstrap classes that will achieve it.  You just need to know what they are and how they work.

Comment: Then you would have to use `col-xs-6`.  `lg` for large, `md` for medium, `sm` for small, `xs` for extra-small.  See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

1 row have 12 cols for you're first code :

```html
<div class = "container">
  <div class = "row">
  <div class = "col-sm-6"></div>
  <div class = "col-sm-push-6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That means you're second div is after the first who takes 6 cols. So you push the second after the first (col-sm-push-6)

This is for the web-responsive, when you're website is on a computer or in a mobile phone, the screen have different size. Bootstrap adapt you're div to the screen.
They're is sm : for small screen, lg : for large screen and md : for middle screen like a tab for exemple.

Comment: I'm confused. If one row has 12 cols, and I used two 6 col divs, shouldn't they fit into 1 row?

Comment: Yes they fit in one row, but if you want a space between us, you can use just 4 space for you're first div and push the second on 6. The most important is in each row you can't take more than 12 cols. It's up to you, you can organize you're div by pushing it.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain for you. I love to teach beginners :-)

- Firstly when we use column of bootstrap it adds '15px' padding from
  right and left. in this way our column looks like '15px' inside from
  wall of container.
- Secondly we use row to overcome the first situation given upper paragraph.
- Thirdly if you are trying to align Centre 2 columns of 6 and 6 then it is impossible to do this because 2 col-sm-6 
  occupy whole container space.
- Fourthly do r&d about bootstrap offset and push properties. also check bootstrap row and columns properties by using code inspector. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use bootstrap, there is class ready made to build your layout :

> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/
>
> **Flex**
>
> Quickly manage the layout, alignment, and sizing of grid columns, navigation, components, and more with a full suite of responsive flexbox utilities. ***For more complex implementations, custom CSS may be necessary***.

---

If you need cols of a fixed width, ***you might need to create your own class here*** .

example:https://jsfiddle.net/cLw2ajro/7/

```css
body {
  background-color: pink;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.mycol {
  background-color: blue;
  height:100px;
  flex:0 0 100px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row d-flex flex-nowrap justify-content-center">
    <div class="mycol m-2 p-4"></div>
    <div class="mycol m-2 p-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color:pink;
}

.row-centered {
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}

.col-centered {
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
    /* reset the text-align */
    text-align:left;
    /* inline-block space fix */
}

 .container {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.col-sm-6 {
    height: 100px;
    max-width:100px;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 1%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "row row-centered">
    <div class = "col-sm-6 col-centered">-</div>
    <div class = "col-sm-6 col-centered">-</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alencarlucas/zq7yLhyc/)

Source: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28529629/how-to-center-divs-in-row-in-bootstrap)